# Using mod_rewrite() on 1and1 shared hosting

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Update**

I couldn't get this to work adding rules to the .htaccess file, in the end I used the Wordpress Rewrite class and added an add_rewrite_rule() to do the re-write which worked perfectly.

**Original Post**

I have been trying to put together a `.htaccess` rule to move parts of the path to a query string. As per https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewritePathInfo.

I have two folders in the root of my webspace, one for `www.mydomain.com` and one for `test.mydomain.com`. My `.htaccess` file is in the `test.mydomain.com` folder, and I want to rewrite `test.mydomain.com/images/parm1/parm2` to `test.mydomain.com/images/?gwpw=parm2&gwpi=parm1`.

If I put garbage in the `.htaccess` file I get a 500 internal server error so I know the file is being read. I also have some existing rules in `.htaccess` from Wordpress that use `mod_rewrite()`, which if I comment out, stop the site redirecting to a 404 error page if you try to access `test.mydomain.com/somegarbage`. So I know `mod_rewrite()` is enabled.

I have read I need to set `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`, so the whole rule I have is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/images/([^/]*)/([^/]*) /images/?gwpw=$1&gwpi=$2 [PT]
```

I have tried this in different parts of the file, removing the leading slash from `/images/?gwpw=...`. I've tried adding a rule that I thought should rewrite every request to a different page like `RewriteRule ^/* /somewhere` but I can't seem to get any rewrite to work.

As this is a shared server I can't access `httpd.conf`.

My entire .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    php_flag session.cookie_httponly on
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/images/([^/]*)/([^/]*) /images/?gwpw=$1&gwpi=$2 [PT]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
```

I am a complete newbie when it comes to .htaccess rules, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm clearly doing something wrong but I can't see the wood for the trees anymore!

Comment: Can you try using `[PT,L]` instead of `[PT]`, please?

Comment: @JanPapenbrock Thanks for the reply, tried that and it makes no difference.